# Select all the minimun and maximun values of the table

Tags: mysql

I have a `SQL table` like this:

| pr_Key | fr_Key | attr_1 | attr_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p_1 | f_1 | 100 | 150 |
| p_2 | f_1 | 150 | 200 |
| p_3 | f_1 | 200 | 250 |
| p_4 | f_2 | 100 | 150 |
| p_5 | f_2 | 150 | 200 |
| p_6 | f_2 | 200 | 250 |

But, I only want to `select` all the `minimum` and `maximum` for `attr_1` and `attr_2` of `fr_Key` just like this:

```
| pr_Key | fr_Key | attr_1 | attr_2 |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
|   p_1  |   f_1  |  100   |  150   | <-- the minimum values of f_1
|   p_3  |   f_1  |  200   |  250   | <-- the maximum values of f_1
|   p_4  |   f_2  |  100   |  150   | <-- the minimum values of f_2
|   p_6  |   f_2  |  200   |  250   | <-- the maximum values of f_2
```

Comment: Although there may be duplicates of the question, this is about two columns, not one, so the suggested duplicate was not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses correlated subqueries in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.attr1 = (select min(t2.attr1) from t t2 where t2.fr_Key = t.fr_Key) or
      t.attr1 = (select max(t2.attr1) from t t2 where t2.fr_Key = t.fr_Key) or
      t.attr2 = (select min(t2.attr2) from t t2 where t2.fr_Key = t.fr_Key) or
      t.attr2 = (select max(t2.attr2) from t t2 where t2.fr_Key = t.fr_Key);
```

EDIT:

Actually, I think you want the minimum and maximum *across both columns*.  If so:

```
select t.*
from t
where least(t.attr1, t.attr2) =
          (select least(min(t2.attr1), min(t2.attr2))
           from t t2
           where t2.fr_Key = t.fr_Key
          ) or
      greatest(t.attr1, t.attr2) =
          (select greatest(max(t2.attr1), max(t2.attr2))
           from t t2
           where t2.fr_Key = t.fr_Key
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT fr_key,1 attr, MIN(attr_1) val FROM my_table GROUP BY fr_key
       UNION
       SELECT fr_key,2, MIN(attr_2) val FROM my_table GROUP BY fr_key
       UNION
       SELECT fr_key,1 attr, MAX(attr_1) val FROM my_table GROUP BY fr_key
       UNION
       SELECT fr_key,2, MAX(attr_2) val FROM my_table GROUP BY fr_key
     ) b
    ON b.fr_key = a.fr_key
   AND CASE WHEN attr = 1 THEN b.val = attr_1 ELSE b.val = attr_2 END
;
```